# How to enable CONFIG_NETFILTER in Kernel?

Tags: kernel, iptables, firewall

I'm trying to install my own Firewall on `ubuntu` using `iptables`. In a tutorial it says, I need the `iptables-Kernelmodule` and the parameter `CONFIG_NETFILTER=Y` in Kernel Configuration. I didn't found a tutorial on web how to edit the Kernel Configuration. Results on Google were to compile an own Kernel, but I just want to edit one Config-Point, so I don't want to make big changes so I thought that this method is the wrong and that there might be an easier/more suitable.

**So how to enable the `CONFIG_NETFILTER` in my Kernel Configuration?/Where can I edit the Config?**

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an Ubuntu kernel, CONFIG_NETFILTER is already enabled for you.

The kernel configuration is only for compiling the kernel, no other reason.

```
grep CONFIG_NETFILTER= /boot/*config*
```

Should let you know if your kernel has it enabled or not.
If you see this:

```
CONFIG_NETFILTER=y
```

It's enabled, if you see this:

```
# CONFIG_NETFILTER is not set
```

Or nothing, [CONFIG_NETFILTER](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NETFILTER.html) is not enabled and the only way to enable it is to re-compile your kernel:

```
apt install build-essential libqt4-dev libncurses5-dev git tmux bc libncurses5 libncurses5-dev
git clone --depth 1 git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git
cd linux
make menuconfig # this bit lets you enable the stuff you want.
make
make modules_install
cp zImage /boot/
```

this assumes a Debian like system that has mainline support.

Comment: I found the config is at `/boot/config.txt`, it is a good way to change the config using `nano`?

Comment: `CONFIG_NETFILTER` is not in the config.txt ...

Answer (score 0):

Thats only needed if you are compiling your kernel from source. If you are using the supplied ubuntu kernel, you don't need to change it, just start adding your iptables rules.

Meanwhile go find a better tutorial.